# AWK, variables and piping: get FILENAME, ID and values on first AWK and rescue on final awk

Tags: bash, variables, awk, pipe

I'm using AWk to get the fields from a csv pool files like that:

```
"Título de trazado: yerba_loca_wt_04"
"N.º","Fecha Tiempo, GMT-03:00","Temp, °C (LGR S/N: 10466177, SEN S/N: 10466177, LBL: Temperatura)","Acoplador separado (LGR S/N: 10466177)","Acoplador adjunto (LGR S/N: 10466177)","Host conectado (LGR S/N: 10466177)","Parado (LGR S/N: 10466177)","Final de archivo (LGR S/N: 10466177)"
1,02/28/14 01:00:00 PM,25.234,Registrado,,,,
2,02/28/14 02:00:00 PM,26.573,,,,,
3,02/28/14 03:00:00 PM,24.653,,,,,
4,02/28/14 04:00:00 PM,24.219,,,,,
5,02/28/14 05:00:00 PM,24.171,,,,,
6,02/28/14 06:00:00 PM,24.315,,,,,
7,02/28/14 07:00:00 PM,24.412,,,,,
```

Then i get the DATE_HOURAM/PM Field to convert in DATE, HOUR24hrs (2 fields) with thath line:

```
awk -F"," '{if (FNR>=3) print $2}' *.csv | awk '{print $1","$2" "$3}'| awk -F, '{system("printf "$1", &  date --date=\""$2"\" +%T")}'
```

The question now is how to get a new file with all columns: $ID, $DATE, $HOUR, $Value1...

I tried to define in first AWK the variables:

```
 awk -F"," -v archivo=FILENAME -v ID=1 -v col3=3 -v col4=4  '{if (FNR>=3) print $2}' *.csv | awk '{print $1","$2" "$3" "archivo }'
```

But that varaibles aren't useful, because they cannont save the values what i want.

I need to constructa new '$archivo.csv' like:

```
$ID, $DATE, $HOUR, $Values
```

Can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the output you are expecting?

Comment: I don't understand why you need multiple `awk` scripts? If you want to get the parts of the date/time use `split(var, " ", $2)`.

Comment: You really need to learn how to use awk as your approach and what you think you need to do to solve your problem are both way off. I recommend the book Effective Awk Programming, Third Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: Well, i need to get the first variables and save on a new file, this new namefile is concatenated from 'post_' and FILENAME.

Comment: I recently yesterday begin yo work with AWK, that's because i'm newbie with this command-i looking for the book, thanks!

Comment: I updated my answer based on your new information about output file name.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `split()` function to get the parts of the `datetime`:

```
awk -F, 'FNR >= 3 { 
    split($2, a, " "); 
    split(a[2], t, ":");
    if (a[3] == "PM") { t[1] += 12; }
    printf("%s,%s %s:%s:%s,", $1, a[1], t[1],t[2],t[3]);
    for (i = 3; i < NF; i++) {printf("%s,", $i); }
    print $NF;
}'
```

Comment: It can be a little more concise: `awk -F, -v OFS=, 'FNR >= 3 {split($2, a, " "); split(a[2], t, ":"); $2 = sprintf("%s %02d:%s:%s", a[1], t[1] + (a[3] == "PM" ? 12 : 0), t[2], t[3]); print}'`

Answer (score 0):

Yea, i'm ok with the date, but the problem now are the ANOTHER variables like the ID, and VALUES who don't remain throw the pipes.

For example

First awk:
    awk -F"," -v archivo=FILENAME '{print $2}' *.csv

I put he pipe. '|' and the second AWK:

```
awk '{print $1","$2" "$3}
```

Then i put the pipe '|' and the third AWK and finally generate the file:

```
awk -F, '{system("printf "$1", &  date --date=\""$2"\" > "post_"$archivo".csv"
```

But the $archivo variable is empty on the third AWk :S

Comment: That's because "archivo" is an awk variable that only exists in the first awk program. You can do this in one single awk call.

Comment: No, that's not even in the ballpark of the right answer. Please read the answers you are being given to your questions (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26026042/using-awk-system-date-convert-data-field-from-csv).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show any expected output so it's a guess what you want the output to look like but whatever that format is all you need is something like:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }
FNR>2 {
    split($2,a,/[ :]/)
    $2 = sprintf("%s,%02d:%s:%s",a[1],a[2]+(a[5]=="PM"?12:0),a[3],a[4])
    print > ("post_" FILENAME)
}

$ awk -f tst.awk *.csv
```

If you have a lot of csv files and aren't using GNU awk and so need to manage how many are open simultaneously change it slightly to:

```
BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }
FNR == 1 { close(fname); fname = "post_" FILENAME }
FNR>2 {
    split($2,a,/[ :]/)
    $2 = sprintf("%s,%02d:%s:%s",a[1],a[2]+(a[5]=="PM"?12:0),a[3],a[4])
    print > fname
}
```